# How can I get time in millisecond from a given time input?

Tags: jquery, timepicker

I am using Jquery Time Picker, Surprisingly, on selecting time it's returning result in format `Sun Dec 31 1899 23:00:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)`
But, I want to get time in millisecond of selected time (more preciously, selected time on today)?

Comment: `var x = new Date('Sun Dec blah blahblah').now()`?

Comment: do you want the difference in milliseconds between a given time and current time?

Comment: Yes, If I need the difference,

Comment: Do you have a link to the particular timepicker plugin you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the returned value into a `Date` object with today's year, month and date and the selected time, using the code below:

```js
var today = new Date();
var selectedTimeToday = new Date(
    today.getFullYear(),
    today.getMonth(),
    today.getDate(),
    value.getHours(),
    value.getMinutes(),
    value.getSeconds()
);
```

If all you want is to get the time in milliseconds for the selected value, then you can use getMilliseconds() or getUTCMilliseconds() to get it:

```js
var timestamp = selectedTimeToday.getMilliseconds();
```

If you need to calculate the number of milliseconds between now and the selected value, do it like this:

```js
var difference = Math.abs(Date.now() - selectedTimeToday);
```

Remove Math.abs if you want to use the sign to indicate whether the selected time is in the future (negative difference) or in the past.